# Accessibility 'Form elements do not have associated labels'

Tags: reactjs

I am doing an accessibility audit test on my site, and I keep getting an error with something to do with my input fields without a label. I have included the label above it using a value from my mapped function. But it is still playing up, does anyone know why it is doing this?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

{optionsList &&
              optionsList.length > 0 &&
              optionsList.map((option, index) => (
                <div className="control">
                  <div className="radio">
             -----     //LABEL IS ADDED HERE!   -----
                  <label htmlFor={option}/>
                    <input
                      name={title}
                      type="radio"
                      value={option}
                      checked={option === selectedValue}
                      id={`${option}`}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    <label
                      className="radio--replace"
                      htmlFor={option}
                      role="presentation"
                    >
                      {option}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```